# How to write a like query in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I have created a select query that functioning well. But now I need to change this to a like query. Can anyone tell me the correct way?

This is my select query structure ->

```
public function getSelectedHotel($id)
{
    $selectedHotel = $this->tableGateway->select(['hotel_id' => $id]);

        return $selectedHotel;
}
```

When I code like this it gives me this error.

Code ->

```
$hotelsByYear = $this->tableGateway->select()->where('date_added like ?',$year.'%');
```

Error ->

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet::where() in

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Zend 2 - TableGateway Where Clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13334220/zend-2-tablegateway-where-clauses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code OR refer the [official document](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.db.sql.html#where-having).

```
$where = new Where();    
$where->like('Field_Name', '%'.$ParamVal.'%');
//use as below
$this->tableGateway->select($where);
```

Don't forget to use `Zend\Db\Sql\Where;`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the documentation: https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.db.table-gateway.html#basic-usage

It should be something like:

```
$hotelsByYear = $this->tableGateway->select(function (Select $select) {
    $select->where->like('date_added', $year.'%');
});
```

Explanation:
Everytime you call $tableGateway->select() the query will be executed, so if you do $tableGateway->select()->where() you call ->where() on the result of the ->select() method, which is obviously a Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet.

Answer (score 0):

$table->select()->where('Field_Name', '%'.$ParamVal.'%');

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a Predicate :

```
$selectedHotel = $this->tableGateway->select([
    'hotel_id' => $id,
    new \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Like('date_added', $year.'%')
]);
```